# Multiple entries in attribute table for multiple buffers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, buffer

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 to draw 500ft buffers around a group of 133 bars.

The numerous buffer tools all produce a single entry in the attribute table for the collected group of buffers instead of one entry for each buffer when I use the dissolve setting.

Is there a way to produce a shapefile of dissolved buffers whose attribute table contains 133 rows, that it, one for each buffer, instead of the default that produces one row for all?

[image: Print screen jpeg of numerous buffers and open buffer attribute table]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're looking at? I am not sure I understand which attribute table (the facilities? the buffer?)

Comment: you mean using a field to define the size of your buffer ? This is one of the option with the buffer tool.

Comment: When you do a Buffer, there's a setting called Dissolve which determines if and how your buffers will be combined with each other after the Buffer is done. It sounds like you need to change your Dissolve type from ALL to NONE.

Comment: Your question contradicts itself - if you want 133 buffers for 133 points, you do *not* want to dissolve (ie set to NONE as Dan C says). Take a look at the graphic in the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000). Do you want overlapping buffers to be combined, but all non-overlapping buffers to be separate? That requires a second step - either Explode/Multi-part to Single Part the dissolved buffers, or Dissolve buffers created without dissolve and not allowing multi-part features. It would be helpful to log in if you want to edit your question.

Comment: I think it will help if you can edit your question to include the precise steps that you performed to produce your graphic.  With those in front of us, and knowing that you want more than one row (and towards 133 rows) in the output attribute table, it will become easy to advise which of your steps needs to be modified.